# Left outer joins with join condition

Tags: sql, join

At times, the following statement is confusing, at least to me, though I have been working with joins for a long time.

The part which is confusing here is, considering second left join

```
SELECT * FROM table1  
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id  
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.id=table3.id;
```

1. Which will be considered as left table - either table1 or table2 (table2 is involved in join condition).
2. If I recall correctly, left join result involves matched results from join condition and unmatched results from left table. If left table is table1 (from point 1.), what will be unmatched rows from table1, as it isn't involved in the join condition.

Comment: 1. reading from left to right it's "left join" refers to the first table. 2.  what do you mean it's not involved in the join condition?

Comment: table1 isn't involved in the second join condition directly , table2.id=table3.id .. right ??

Comment: @Sukhhhh The result of the left join between Table1 and Table2 is what is joined in the second condition. So yes, Table1 is involved in the second join directly. You won't be able to join any data from Table3 that doesn't have matching ID values with Table1 AND Table2. Please see the update to my answer after the sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will return all of the rows that are in `Table1`. It will join the rows from `Table2` only where the `id` values are equal between `Table1` and `Table2`. It will also join the rows from `Table3` where the `id` values are equal between the result of the join of (`Table1` AND `Table2`) and `Table3`. So if the first join between `Table1` and `Table2` has produced a NULL result (no equivalent `id` value in `Table2`), then the second join will also produce a NULL result. For example (using SQL Server):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE([ID] INT, [Value] VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(1, 'Table 1 ID 1')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(2, 'Table 1 ID 2')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(3, 'Table 1 ID 3')

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE([ID] INT, [Value] VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(1, 'Table 2 ID 1')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(3, 'Table 2 ID 3')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(5, 'Table 2 ID 5')

DECLARE @Table3 TABLE([ID] INT, [Value] VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES(2, 'Table 3 ID 2')
INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES(3, 'Table 3 ID 3')
INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES(5, 'Table 3 ID 5')

SELECT * 
FROM @Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN @Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
LEFT JOIN @Table3 T3 ON T2.ID = T3.ID
```

This query will produce the following results:

```
ID  Value          ID   Value           ID    Value
-----------------------------------------------------------
1   Table 1 ID 1   1    Table 2 ID 1    NULL  NULL
2   Table 1 ID 2   NULL NULL            NULL  NULL
3   Table 1 ID 3   3    Table 2 ID 3    3     Table 3 ID 3
```

To answer your question, `Table1` is involved on the second join because the second join will only contain rows from `Table2` that were able to be joined with `Table1`. In other words, the second join isn't `Table2` to `Table3`, it's the result of the left join of `Table1` and `Table2` to `Table3`. So in my example, even though `Table2` and `Table3` both have records with an `ID` of 5, those records are not included in the result set because `Table1` does not have a record with an `ID` of 5.

Comment: more clear now .. thanks rsbarro for sharing lot of information :-)

Comment: I don't think that it is correct to ascribe an ordering to the joins.   In your example, the results would be the same if table2 and table3 were joined first, and then that result joined with table1. To illustrate, consider the case case t1 left outer join t2 on t1.a = t2.a join t3 on t1.a = t3.a . (2nd join not outer)  Certainly here, the dbms may decide to perform the t1xt3 join first, possibly to great performance advantage as it may eliminate many rows.  My point is that you generally cannot assume a processing order of joins.

Comment: @ElroyFlynn I see what you're saying. I wasn't approaching the question from the standpoint of how the dbms interally executes the query, I was just trying to answer the question of which rows are going to wind up in the result set. Regardless of how the dbms does the execution, you still are not going to wind up with any records from table3 that aren't in table1 and table2.

Answer (score 2):

1. The result of joining `table1` and `table2` is the left table in the second join.
2. If you have `id 1` in `table1` and no `id 1` in `table2` but `table3` contains `id 1` then the row for `id 1` will be like:

```
table1.id  table2.id  table3.id
1          NULL       NULL
```

Joins are computed in the order of declaration. This means that you are joining `table3` to the result of `table1` and `table2`.